# git not changing crlf to lf when changing encoding of a file

Tags: windows, git

I have a utf-16 file checked in. Git treats it as `binary` file.

Steps :
In windows :

1. I change the encoding of file to utf-8 in windows.
2. I commit the change.

In linux :

3. I pull the branch.
4. In git status, i see the file as modified even though i have not touched it here in this repo.

Reason : git didn't change crlf to lf in step 2 above.

If i do the same exercise in linux and then pull in windows, it is no issue.

As during diff or commit, it says :  `warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in Foo.xml`

*What is the reason that git didn't automatically change crlf to lf when destination file formatting is recognized by it as text ?*

Note : i have a lot of other files and with them crlf-lf conversion works good. It is only during changing encoding of format recognized by git as binary (here utf-16) to utf-8 (text format for git), it does not do conversion.

Is it because base-line in commit is of binary file ?
Also, it behaves correctly in linux atleast.

Are my observations right ?

Comment: Any new changes in my converted file are also good. It is just that during that commit it does not do crlf-lf conversion and git gets confused in linux.

Comment: The problem is that you appear to be storing an XML file with UTF-16 encoding. That doesn't make sense in itself. Store it as UTF-8, like everyone else, Git will no longer assume that it's binary, and perform the EOL conversion as desired.

Comment: @llnspectable its not about xml or utf-8 or utf-16.. its about changing encoding from X to Y where X is binary format for git and Y is text format.

Comment: You can teach Git to not interpret UTF-16 as binary. To my knowledge it would still not be able to convert EOL markers, at least not in a clean way. The question really is: Why use UTF-16 for text interchange? Git doesn't natively understand it, so you are looking for issues, if you continue down that route.

Comment: @llnspectable That is what i am doing now. I can't go back in time and reset the public history. My question is around the issue that i hit when i change the encoding to utf-8.

Comment: You don't have any issues when using UTF-8. Git natively understands UTF-8, and can perform EOL conversions. If you need to fix a bug, you can certainly change the public history. Using UTF-16 in a cross-platform project is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the encoding, `git rm --cached file_name && git add file_name` works good.

This way git takes newer encoding of file.